# Can't install GWT Toolkit for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, installation, toolkit

I can't install GWT Toolkit on my Eclipse, can anyone help me with that? I need it for Windows Builder Pro...

```
    Your original request has been modified.
  "WindowBuilder Core" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
  "WindowBuilder XML Core (requires Eclipse WTP/WST)" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.v201109091335 (org.eclipse.platform 3.7.1.v201109091335)
    Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.v201106131736 (org.eclipse.platform 3.7.0.v201106131736)
    Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v201209141800 (org.eclipse.platform 4.2.1.v201209141800)
    Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v201202080800 (org.eclipse.platform 3.7.2.v201202080800)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0,3.8.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.5.1.20120917-1257]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE 1.5.1.20120828-0743 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20120828-0743)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.platform [4.2.0,5.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee [1.5.1.20120828-0743]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f)
    To: org.eclipse.platform [3.7.0.v201106131736]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK)
    To: org.eclipse.platform [3.7.1.v201109091335]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
    To: org.eclipse.platform [3.7.2.v201202080800]
```

I'll attach a screenshot to show where I'm getting this error...
[image]

Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: @Jarrod: No, the problem is, that "Google Plugin for Eclipse" cannot be installed! It can't be installed, because it requires `org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0,3.8.0)`.

Comment: Well I barely understand anything in this error. But deselecting either of those two things you mentioned or both doesn't help installing it?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, why this question was closed. The answer to the problem isn't obvious at all, the error message is almost impossible to read, if you don't know Eclipse's plugin structure, features and dependencies. Moreover, the official [GWT Eclipse plugin page](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse) still doesn't mention the 4.2 version of the update site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Eclipse version is probably newer than 3.7.x. So instead of http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7, use the update site http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

Comment: Thanks, seems to have helped!

Comment: But I already have the 4.2 Toolkit installed. Typical case of a wizzard trying to be more intelligent then the user and failing miserably.